# Why is $\lim_{x \to -7} \dfrac{x+5}{x^2+49}$ = $-\infty$?

Tags: limits

Why is $\lim_{x \to -7} \dfrac{x+5}{x^2+49}$ = $-\infty$ ?

Here is my thought process:

$\lim_{x \to -7} \dfrac{x+5}{x^2+49}$ = $\lim_{x \to -7} \dfrac{x/x^2+5/x^2}{x^2/x^2+49/x^2}$ = $\lim_{x \to -7} \dfrac{1/x+5/x^2}{1+49/x^2}$ =
$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{-7}+\dfrac{5}{49}}{1+\dfrac{49}{49}}$ = $\dfrac{-1}{49}$

But apparently the answer is $-\infty$

Comment: You are correct.  The problem likely has a typo in the sign of the denominator.

Comment: Who said it was? If the denominator was $x^2-49$ it wouldn't be, either. And why does your body and your title differ (one says $-\infty$ the other just $\infty$.

Comment: Someone just down voted your question, so I neutralized by giving it an up vote.

Comment: Sorry I changed the title to reflect consistency.  The answer is apparently $-\infty$.

Comment: With a $+$ in the denominator, the limit is finite (indeed the function is continuous). With a $-$ in the denominator, one side gives $+\infty$ and the other side gives $-\infty$.

Comment: Ok, i think I must have copied the problem down incorrectly from whiteboard. you guys are right.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your reasoning for this limit. However, an easier method to find the limit is through direct substitution. $$\lim_{x\to-7}\frac{x+5}{x^2+49} = \frac{-7+5}{(-7)^2+49} = -\frac{1}{49}$$